# Testing Instrumental (Espresso) Login using MockWebServer with Retrofit

Tags: android, android-espresso, mockwebserver

I'm looking to create an instrumental (espresso) test from LoginActivy.
I'm using Mock's for API calls, unfortunately my app keeps calling my REAL API.

Below is my test code

```
@Test
public void loginSuccessTest() throws Exception {
    String fileName = "login/success_login_with_user_pass.json";
    try {
        Thread.sleep(16);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    onView(withId(R.id.txt_username)).perform(replaceText(USER_VALID));

    onView(withId(R.id.txt_password)).perform(replaceText(PASS_VALID), closeSoftKeyboard());

    server.enqueue(
            new MockResponse()
                    .setResponseCode(200)
                    .setBody(RestServiceTestHelper.getStringFromFile(getInstrumentation().getContext(), fileName)));


    ViewInteraction appCompatButton = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.btn_login), withText("Acessar")));
    appCompatButton.perform(scrollTo(), click());

    onView(withId(R.id.btn_main_menu)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

When the test passes the code below, the test calls the REAL API.

```
ViewInteraction appCompatButton = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.btn_login), withText("Acessar")));
    appCompatButton.perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

This is the code before the test starts

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    server = new MockWebServer();
    server.start(8681);
}
```

The application is using the productFlavors configuration:

```
productFlavors {
    ui_tests {
        buildConfigField STRING, 'HOST', '"http://localhost:8681/"'
    }
}
```

I do not know what else to do to avoid calls in my REAL API, can anyone help me?

Configuring the Android Studio Variable Environment
[image: Build Variants]

Comment: Are you sure you are building and running the test on the ui_tests flavor build?

Comment: I think so, I checked the Android Studio settings.

Comment: Cant see anything wrong with the above code. You might need to show where you are setting the host url

Comment: Is the host configuration in the @Before?
And in my environment of variavéis in productFlavors?
I put this in my code, but I'm not sure I did it the right way.
Can you show me how the host configuration is?

Comment: Are you setting the URL of retrofit to point to your localhost? like here https://github.com/riggaroo/android-retrofit-test-examples/blob/master/RetrofitTestExample/app/src/main/java/za/co/riggaroo/retrofittestexample/MainActivity.java#L52